# Confirm bug in t-test calculation

Tags: t-test, c#

**Question**

Suspected a bug in a T-Test c# code and ask if somebody could confirm.

**Sidenote**

My question might be a candidate to be closed, as "Bugs in the software (report them to the makers of that software)". No worries I have already done that, but it is not only "using a statistical software" my question is more like "correctly implement an algorithm".

The complete C# code (267 lines) I am re-using to calculate Welch T-Test could be found in the MSDN Magazine November 2015. [Test Run - The T-Test Using C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/november/test-run-the-t-test-using-csharp)

**Background**

If I am correct in understanding the wikipedia formulas for Welch T-Test.

[image: T-Test Formula at wikipedia]

Then the divisor of the summand below the square root in the t-formula, should just be the size N of the sample1 and sample2.

**The Problem**

In the code I spotted n will be reduced by 1.

I suspect these lines to be not correct when doing the t calculation and doing the wrong division for the StdDev.

```
    int n1 = x.Length;
    int n2 = y.Length;
    double meanX = sumX / n1;
    double meanY = sumY / n2;

    double sumXminusMeanSquared = 0.0; // calculate (sample) variances
    double sumYminusMeanSquared = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
        sumXminusMeanSquared += (x[i] - meanX) * (x[i] - meanX);

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; ++i)
        sumYminusMeanSquared += (y[i] - meanY) * (y[i] - meanY);

    double varX = sumXminusMeanSquared / (n1 - 1); // and here's the bug
    double varY = sumYminusMeanSquared / (n2 - 1); // and here's the bug

    // t statistic
    double top = (meanX - meanY);
    double bot = Math.Sqrt((varX / n1) + (varY / n2));
    double t = top / bot;
```

This will be correct for the df calculation that is directly below (degree of freedom). But not for calculating t.  The lower my input sample size is, the more effect this bug would have. Correct?

The "corrected" code of this section:

```
double sumX = 0.0; // calculate means
double sumY = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    sumX += x[i];

for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; ++i)
    sumY += y[i];

int n1 = x.Length;
int n2 = y.Length;
double meanX = sumX / n1;
double meanY = sumY / n2;

double sumXminusMeanSquared = 0.0; // calculate (sample) variances
double sumYminusMeanSquared = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    sumXminusMeanSquared += (x[i] - meanX) * (x[i] - meanX);

for (int i = 0; i < n2; ++i)
    sumYminusMeanSquared += (y[i] - meanY) * (y[i] - meanY);

double varX = sumXminusMeanSquared / (n1 );  //*** and here now my corrections to not divide with n-1 
double varY = sumYminusMeanSquared / (n2 );  //*** and here now my corrections to not divide with n-1 

// t statistic
double top = (meanX - meanY);
double bot = Math.Sqrt((varX / n1) + (varY / n2));
double t = top / bot;

Console.WriteLine($"mean of x = {meanX}");
Console.WriteLine($"mean of y = {meanY}");

varX = sumXminusMeanSquared / (n1 - 1);
varY = sumYminusMeanSquared / (n2 - 1);


// df mildly tricky
// http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#parametric_methods/unpaired_t.htm
double num = ((varX / n1) + (varY / n2)) *
    ((varX / n1) + (varY / n2));
double denomLeft = ((varX / n1) * (varX / n1)) / (n1 - 1);
double denomRight = ((varY / n2) * (varY / n2)) / (n2 - 1);
double denom = denomLeft + denomRight;
double df = num / denom;

double p = Student(t, df); // cumulative two-tail density
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I have caught all the nuances of your question, but as far as the "n-1" goes, your corrections are wrong: the $s_i^2$ are *estimates* of the variances and require the divisions by the $n_i-1.$  Generally, when coding statistical procedures it is crucial to have some example data and known results (from textbooks or other software) for testing.

Comment: hmm... on wikipedia for calculate ν (degree of freedom) they explicitly say use the n-1 and for calculate t they say nothing, they just write n1 and n2. So I assumed it needs to be used plain n. Thanks for your hint with using exampled data with known results, ... searching for it now...

Comment: It seems, that in fact I need to use n-1. "If you have a sample of the population rather than the whole population, then you should use [...] (count - 1)" [Standard Deviation in LINQ on stackoverflo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2253903/3090544). This small sentence brought back what I have learnt.